# What are the pros and cons of Limbo, and what weapons are optimal for him?

Tags: warframe

I'm getting Limbo in *Warframe*, and I have a couple of questions about them.

1. Is Limbo better or worse than Limbo Prime? Is it worth farming for Limbo Prime?
2. Is Limbo better than Volt in an average situation?
3. What situations is Limbo good in, and what situations do they not do so well in?
4. What weapons are best for him (melee and ranged, please)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In general, Prime Warframes have higher stats than their common varieties. This has made them superior to their common counterparts in every aspect other than shield-gating.  As I'm not an expert at post-rework shield-gating, I cant say if this is still true, but it's safe to say the Primed Warframe will never be a waste of time and effort. Should you choose to get rid of a common Warframe, consider feeding it to your Helminth instead of selling it. Talk to Son on Deimos if you have questions.
2. I tend to use Limbo in very specific solo situations, Lua Spy & Kuria hunting come to mind. Volt on the other hand is considered an excellent choice for Eidolon hunts. Think, "right tool for the job."
3. See 2.
4. This is an odd question. Generally folks talk about builds for Warframes & then pick weapons to match a purpose. You may want to browse [the wiki's disposition page](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Riven_Mods/Weapon_Dispos) looking for low Disposition weapons as they generally fare well in the meta (or are too new to have been disregarded by the players).

Answer (score 1):

To sort of address #3:

Limbo's gimmick is that when you dash, are targeted by his first ability, or are within the zone created by his 4th ability, you are unable to interact with things outside. Friendly warframes within the zone can affect enemies with their abilities, but your bullets will pass harmlessly through enemies unless they are Banished as well.

This inability to interact also includes locked doors, consoles, and items you need to pick up, such as the data terminals for Mobile Defense missions. So if you use his 4 to surround a mobile defense target, you will not be able to activate the target until the bubble collapses. This is prone to griefing, as it prevents your teammates from accessing the target, but it is also useful, as enemies will not be able to damage the terminal until they walk inside the bubble.

This combines well with his Stasis ability, which freezes enemies who are Banished. So a player might cast the Stasis ability then place his ability 4 bubble over a target that needs protecting. Enemies will be unable to damage the target from range, and if they walk into the bubble they count as banished, and will be frozen by Stasis.